# Device ACL not visible in docker container

Tags: docker, acl

There is a serial device which I get access through ACL which can be seen on the host OS:

```
fgervais@fgervais-System-Product-Name:~$ getfacl /dev/ttyUSB3 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/ttyUSB3
# owner: root
# group: dialout
user::rw-
user:fgervais:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

I then map it in a container:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/project -w /project --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /etc/group:/etc/group -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd --device /dev/ttyUSB3:/dev/ttyUSB3 espressif/idf:v3.3.2 bash
```

However inside the container I don't have access anymore:

```
fgervais@caee53c47877:/project$ id
uid=1000(fgervais) gid=1000(fgervais) groups=1000(fgervais)

fgervais@caee53c47877:/project$ getfacl /dev/ttyUSB3 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/ttyUSB3
# owner: root
# group: dialout
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---
```

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: If you need host devices, the host user ID space, and the host filesystem, you're gaining very little from Docker; I'd run this directly on the host as in your first example.  What _is_ the host OS here?

Comment: If I'm not in the docker container there is nothing of interest that I can run since I don't have the dependencies, they only are in the container.

Comment: The host OS is Ubuntu 18.04.5

Comment: @DavidMaze, what do you mean by host devices? What about CPU? GPU? RAM? USB? Filesystem? Do you think those things are useless in docker containers?

Comment: A specific design goal of Docker – a key reason to run things in Docker containers at all – is that containers _can't_ access the host's filesystem or USB devices, giving the system an additional layer of protection from rogue processes.  If you want something to act exactly like it's on the host without Docker's isolation features, a container might not be an appropriate implementation choice.